# How to make the WebView2 fit and full the Window (adaptive size effect or full - screen)?

Tags: wpf, webview2

I tried to set HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" &  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
but it was not work.

```
<Window
    x:Class="Y.Shen12DP.PLCT.WebWidow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Y.Shen12DP.PLCT"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
    Title="WebWidow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <wv2:WebView2
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Source="https://www.microsoft.com/" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A10Kj.png)

Could you tell me how to do it (adaptive size effect or full - screen)?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will ensure the WebView2 fills the WPF Window. To make it full screen you need to make the WPF Window full screen which is described elsewhere on StackOverflow: [Full screen in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920067/full-screen-in-wpf-application). Once the WPF Window is full screen the WebView2 should be full screen as well.

Comment: well,I found a property --- ZoomFactor, 
so,I can change content's width & height in webview